# How can I execute a FutureBuilder future on an Autorouter tabs more than once?

Tags: flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I am currently trying to execute a FutureBuilder future function in an Autorouter - the library (https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#tab-navigation) - and it works perfectly. However, as I am using a FutureBuilder in the tabs, the future is only executed once - the first time I access the tab - and isn't re-executed again when I leave the tab and come back to it. I would like to be able to execute the future function every time I access the tab since the future is reading data from the database.

I have tried the following:

- making the widget stateful and executing `setState` function to force a rebuild
- using the overridden function `didChangeDependencies`
- override the `deactivate` function of the widget

None of the above seem to work.

And after going through the documentation of the Autoroute library, I haven't come across any explanation on how to force a rebuild of the current tab.

I welcome any suggestions.

Thank you

NB: I'm using Flutter to make a mobile application, the solution doesn't necessarily have to work on a web application.

**Tab View**

```
class MyTabView extends StatelessWidget {
  MyTabView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final tabRoutes = [
    TabRoute1(),
    TabRoute2(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AutoTabsScaffold(
      routes: tabRoutes,
      bottomNavigationBuilder: (_, tabRouter) {
        return BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: tabRouter.activeIndex,
          onTap: tabRouter.setActiveIndex,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: BaseIcon(
                svgFileName: 'calendar.svg',
              ),
              label: LocaleKeys.careProfessionalLabelProfile.tr(),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: BaseIcon(
                svgFileName: 'wallet.svg',
              ),
              label: LocaleKeys.careProfessionalLabelChat.tr(),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

**Tab with child that contains FutureBuilder**

```
class TabRoute2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const TabRoute2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TabRoute2> createState() => _TabRoute2State();
}

class _TabRoute2State extends State<TabRoute2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        // ---- END SPACER
        Expanded(
          child: ShowFutureData(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**ShowFutureData**

```
class ShowFutureData extends StatefulWidget {

  const ShowFutureData({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<ShowFutureData> createState() =>
      _ShowFutureDataState();
}

class _ShowFutureDataState extends State<ShowFutureData> {
  late FutureDataObjectProvider futureObjectProvider;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureObjectProvider = context.read<FutureDataObjectProvider>();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    retrieved = futureObjectProvider.retrieveAllData();

    return FutureBuilder(
      future: retrieved,    // only executed when the tab is first accessed
      initialData: const [],
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // do something with the data
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign the `future` to recall the future.

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: myFuture,
```

Then reassign it again

```dart
myFuture = getData();
```

Comment: should I reassign it in the build method? I tried reassigning it however it didn't seem to take

Comment: Inside build method might cause unnecessary API call, you can pass `onTap` function to listen the changes to trigger api call. I think you are using riverpod, try futureProvider/streamProvider, it will be better I think.